# How can I get selected value of a custom dropdown menu in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input, dropdown, styled-components

I'm using styled components and typescript and I want to get the value of the selected option of a custom dropdown but I don't understand why it doesn't work. If I remove the opacity from the native select element I can see that the value gets updated but that's not what I want. (I'm just starting out with typescript) Here's my dropdown:

```
  label?: string;
  value?: string;
  iconId?: IconId;
}

const SelectGroup = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
`;

const NativeSelect = styled.select`
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
`;

const CustomSelect = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid;
  line-height: 2rem;
  width: 25rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background: ${theme.color.darkGrey};
  color: ${theme.color.white};
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in;

  ${NativeSelect}:focus + & {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  }
`;

const IconContainer = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.4rem;
  right: 2rem;
  pointer-events: none;
`;

const InputLabel = styled.label`
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  color: ${theme.color.white};
  font-size: ${theme.font.size.small};
`;

export const SelectInput: FC<SelectProps> = ({
  label,
  value,
  iconId,
  children,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
      <SelectGroup>
        <NativeSelect value={value}>{children}</NativeSelect>
        <CustomSelect>
          <IconContainer>
            <Icon iconId={iconId} />
          </IconContainer>
        </CustomSelect>
      </SelectGroup>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
 const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const updateInputValue = (value: string): void => {
    setInputValue(value);
  };

          <SelectInput
            label="Select"
            iconId="select"
            defaultValue={inputValue}
            onChange={e => updateInputValue(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          </SelectInput>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed `value` prop in the SelectInput. `defaultValue` only sets the value on initial load, if we want to change that we update value property. As the component is a controlled, value of SelectInput changes, we need to update that.

```
 <SelectInput
    label="Select"
    iconId="select"
    defaultValue={inputValue}
    value={inputValue}
    onChange={e => updateInputValue(e.target.value)}
>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</SelectInput>
```